# how to get results from Athena for the past week?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I am using Amazon Athena to get all console login that happened in past week, right now i am able to just get all the console logins regardless of the data. I need to modify the below query so that this query picks up all the aws console logins that happened in last week always.

```
WITH events AS (
  SELECT
    event.eventVersion,
    event.eventID,
    event.eventTime,
    event.eventName,
    event.eventType,
    event.eventSource,
    event.awsRegion,
    event.sourceIPAddress,
    event.userAgent,  
    event.userIdentity.type AS userType,
    event.userIdentity.arn AS userArn,
    event.userIdentity.principalId as userPrincipalId,
    event.userIdentity.accountId as userAccountId,
    event.userIdentity.userName as userName
  FROM cloudtrail.events
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST (Records) AS r (event)
)
SELECT userName,sourceIPAddress,eventName,eventTime FROM events WHERE eventName='ConsoleLogin';
```

The eventTime looks like": 
[image]

T

Comment: Sorry, but your question is unclear. Are you simply seeking the ability to specify a date range on the query?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yes , i want to add a dynamic query that would only get me the console logins  from current date to past 7 days

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If that column is coming through as text, you could convert it into a timestamp. I found that Amazon Athena can convert `'2016-05-03 05:46:00'` into a timestamp, so use a `replace()` function to get it into the right format:

```
select cast(replace(replace('2016-05-03T05:46:00Z', 'Z'), 'T', ' ') as timestamp)
```

Therefore, in your `WITH` section, replace `event.eventType` with:

```
cast(replace(replace(event.eventType, 'Z'), 'T', ' ') as timestamp) AS eventType,
```

You can then use standard `WHERE` statements against the date, such as:

```
WHERE eventType > '2017-04-01'
```

Or for the past week (based on the [Presto documentation](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html)):

```
WHERE eventType > current_date - interval '7' day
```

Comment: So if i want to get the past week , then?

Comment: I've added an example for the past week.

Comment: It says : INVALID_CAST_ARGUMENT: Value cannot be cast to timestamp: AwsApiCall

Comment: Is your `eventTime` field a `timestamp` or a `string`? If it is already a timestamp, you can just use it directly.

Comment: If i run it without the cast , it says SYNTAX_ERROR: line 20:110: '>' cannot be applied to varchar, date

Comment: Why did you apply the change to `eventType`? Your original question was asking about `eventTime`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142436/discussion-between-kittystone-and-john-rotenstein).

Answer (score 6):

You can use [from_iso8601_timestamp](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#:~:text=from_iso8601_timestamp) for the conversion like for example

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE from_iso8601_timestamp(my_iso_field) > current_timestamp - interval '7' day
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE from_iso8601_timestamp(eventtime) > date_add('week', -, now())
```

From [here](https://www.gorillastack.com/blog/real-time-events/cloudtrail-athena-query/).

Answer (score -3):

The below query is tested and worked for me.

```
select * table_name where date(column_name) >= (current_date - interval '7' day)
```